# Reading output spatial reference from geoprocessing service in Python toolbox (.pyt) service?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, coordinate-system, geoprocessing-service, python-toolbox

I know I could just create a custom parameter but it seems there's already a built in method here to specify the output spatial reference - I just have no idea how to read it.

I've tried checking `arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem` but it's null at runtime.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to read it? I'm 99% sure you cant read it due to how the gp service framework it setup. But it does what it's supposed to: return the final geometries in whatever spatial ref you've set.

Comment: @KHibma There are occasions where you need more than just a black box framework.  I suppose we're using a technically unsupported workflow by packaging and returning json ourselves (relying on the framework to package layers added a very noticeable and unacceptable amount of overhead).  I can see your point for our case, but I can imagine there are likely some other situations where it'd be good to read that information without just trusting it will be done.